# Pointers application in C array

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, dereference

I write down below code exactly,
and it's supposed to yield "2036, 2036, 2036" but it keeps returning 8-9 digits weird random value whenever I press "Run" button repeatedly.

Anyone knows about it?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main() 
  { 
  unsigned int x[4][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, 
                       {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}};
  printf("%u, %u, %u", x+3, *(x+3), *(x+2)+3);
  }
```

Comment: Why do you think the expected output should be '2036, 2036, 2036'

Comment: `x` is. two dimensional array, what is `*(x+3)` according to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared a two-dimensional array

```
unsigned int x[4][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, 
                        {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}};
```

Used in the argument expressions in the call pf `printf`

```
printf("%u, %u, %u", x+3, *(x+3), *(x+2)+3);
```

it is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `unsigned int ( * )[3]`.

So `x + 3` is a pointer to the forth row of the array that you are trying to output as an unsigned int that results in undefined behavior.

The expression `*( x + 3 )` yields the forth row of the array that is implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element of the row. So the address of the first element of the forth row of the array is outputted as an unsigned int that again invokes undefined behavior.

The expression `*(x+2)` gives the first element of the third row as it is described above. So the expression `*(x+2)+3` yields the address of the memory after the last element of the third row.

Just rewrite the call of `printf` like

```
printf("%p, %u, %u\n", ( void * )( x+3 ), **(x+3), **(x+2)+3);
```

And you will get the address of the forth row, the value of the first element of the forth row (10) and the value of the first element of the third row (7) plus 3 that is 10.

Otherwise you need to write

```
printf("%p, %p, %p\n", ( void * )( x+3 ), ( void * )( *(x+3) ), ( void * )( *(x+2)+3 ) );
```

to output the original expression that have pointer types.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `*(*(x+2)+3)`?

Comment: [I don't get the behavior you're describing.](https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/YellowExcitingInterpreter)  `**(x+3)` works, though.

Comment: @Irelia I am sorry. I was not attentive.:)

Comment: @MisoKorea Either use printf("%p, %u, %u\n", ( void * )( x+3 ), **(x+3), **(x+2)+3); and the output will be some address, 10, 10. Or this printf("%p, %p, %p\n", ( void * )( x+3 ), ( void * )( *(x+3) ), ( void * )( *(x+2)+3 ) ); and the output will consist from three addresses. The same result you will get in visual studio.

Comment: Thanks for all of your feedback! I added "printf("%p, %p, %p\n", ( void * )( x+3 ), ( void * )( *(x+3) ), ( void * )( *(x+2)+3 ) )";, but unfortunately.. it doesn't work on my visual code.. do you think it's compiler issue..? It yields such answers like "000000393b1ff8d4, 000000393b1ff8d4, 000000393b1ff8d4"

Comment: I thought that the result should be “2036, 2036, 2036”, and my logic is as following..

2D array consists of several 1D arrays. And above 2D array consist of 4 sets of 1D array which has 3 elements for each.  
1) So,  x+3 returns "2036" as pointer points out address for 1st element of 4th 2D array.  
2) *(x+3) returns "2036" as it means address of 1st element of 4th 1D array (which belong to 4th 2D array).  
3) *(x+2)+3 returns "2036" as it means address of 1st element of 4th 1D array. (which belong to 4th 2D array).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thx for your support!! now it does work with "printf("%p, %u, %u\n", ( void * )( x+3 ), **(x+3), **(x+2)+3); " and it returns "0000007c949ff904, 10, 10".  But why it returns "000000b5f07ff954, 4034918740, 4034918740" if I type the code only one asterisk mark "printf("%p, %u, %u\n", ( void * )( x+3 ), *(x+3), *(x+2)+3);" instead of "000000b5f07ff954, 2036, 2036"

Comment: @MisoKorea As I pointed to in the answer  there are outputted addresses as objects of the type unsigned int that results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @MisoKorea If the answer resolved your confusion about pointers and arrays then to close the question select the best answer. In this case your reputation will be increased.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thx for your support :) I take your answer but don't know whether it's chosen as best answer as this is my first time to use it.

Comment: @MisoKorea Thanks. You have done all correctly.:)